# I'm trying to interpolate and find the minimum x of the interpolation in C (Possibly with secant method)

Tags: c, interpolation

I want to create my own C function to interpolate some data points and find an accurate minimum (Overall project is audio frequency tuning, and I'm using the YIN algorithm which is working well). I am implementing this on a digital DSP K22F ARM chip, so I want to minimize floating point multiplies as much as possible to implement within the interrupt while the main function pushes to a display and #/b indicators.

I have gotten to the point where I need to interpolate I have implemented the algorithm, found the *integer* minimum, and now need to interpolate. Currently I am trying to parabolically interpolate using the 3 points I have. [I have found one that works within a small margin of error](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e176/lectures/NM/node25.html) Most interpolation functions seem to only be made between two points.

It seems as though the [secant method on this page](https://nickcdryan.com/2017/09/13/root-finding-algorithms-in-python-line-search-bisection-secant-newton-raphson-boydens-inverse-quadratic-interpolation-brents/) would work well for my application. However, I am at a loss for how to combine the 3 points with this 2 point method. Maybe I am going about this the wrong way?

- Can someone help me implement the secant method of interpolation?

I found some example code that gets the exact same answer as my code.

Example code:

```
betterTau = minTau + (fc - fa) / (2 * (2 * fb - fc - fa));
```

My code:

```
newpoint = b + ((fa - fb)*(c-b).^2 - (fc - fb)*(b-a)^2) / ...
    (2*((fa-fb)*(c-b)+(fc-fb)*(b-a)))
```

where the x point values are a, b, and c. The values of each point is fa, fb, and fc, respectively

Currently I am just simulating in MATLAB before I put it on the board which is why the syntax isn't C. Mathematically, I am not seeing how these two equations are equivalent.

- Can someone explain to me how these two functions are equivalent?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does any of this have to do with C?

Comment: If you posted codes than a compare and equivalentcy explanation is possible.  For a theoretical explanation why things are the same, another site would be better.

Comment: @melphomene I had to specify C because there are some questions similar to this, but their answers all are just essentially a built-in function from a library that doesn't help at all. Additionally, this is specifically questioning about implementing a 3 point secant method in C.